# Update the table with 2 column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I want to update the table value comparing with two column values.

Query

```
UPDATE  acc SET slloc =
  (SELECT  Location
    FROM   Duplication$
    WHERE  Duplication$.GROUP1 = acc.grpcd 
         AND acc.ccode = Duplication$.div)
```

The above query showing error as

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
>       The statement has been terminated.

How can i change my query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just rewrite your UPDATE to use a JOIN and you can update as many rows as you like...

```
UPDATE a SET slloc = d.Location
FROM acc a
JOIN Duplication$ d ON d.GROUP1 = a.grpcd 
                AND d.div = a.ccode
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message means that there is more than one `Location` where:

```
Duplication$.GROUP1 = acc.grpcd AND acc.ccode = Duplication$.div
```

is true. You need to see when is that possible and if necessary rethink your strategy.